# Angular compare time via variables

Tags: angularjs, time, comparison

I am storing the time in a variable to compare it with another one
and so, to have a response ifi my variable is >14:00 or <14:00
I do not know (and documenation does not support), how to store the "14:00" in the second variable..

```
var time = ed.DateTimeTo;
var checktime=(??);
if (time > checktime) {
console.log("Time is >14:00");
} else
console.log("Time is <14:00!");
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following mechanism to compare two time strings:

```
function dateCompare(time1,time2) {
  var t1 = new Date();
  var parts = time1.split(":");
  t1.setHours(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2],0);
  var t2 = new Date();
  parts = time2.split(":");
  t2.setHours(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2],0);

  // returns 1 if greater, -1 if less and 0 if the same
  if (t1.getTime()>t2.getTime()) return 1;
  if (t1.getTime()<t2.getTime()) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

If you have a complete date in `ed.DateTimeTo`, then you can simply use:

```
var time = new Date(ed.DateTimeTo);
var checktime = new Date(ed.DateTimeTo).setHours('14','00','00',0); //This will set time to 14:00:00 for current day to compare 
if (time > checktime) {
console.log("Time is >14:00");
} else
console.log("Time is <14:00!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response, I met another way in which I extract the time from the whole datetime variable and compare it with "14":

```
   var hoursfromdate = ed.DateTimeTo.getHours();
                        if (hoursfromdate > "14") {
                            console.log("not a valid time!");
                        } else
                            console.log("valid time!");
```